# Parsing a character array from excel to a C++ dll file for excel

Tags: c++, arrays, excel, dll, pass-by-reference

I am trying to build a dll for excel. It is expected to take a character array as input and do the replacement of _, @ and .. Standalone code works, but when compiling as dll, I am getting the error:

please help.

```
char __stdcall convert(char  (&input)[64])
{
char temp[64];
int i,j,len,rem;
for(i=0,j=0;input[i]!='\0';i++,j++)
{
    if(input[i]=='_')
    {
        temp[j]='%';
        temp[j+1]='5';
        temp[j+2]='F';
        j=j+2;
    }

    else if(input[i]=='@')
    {
        temp[j]='%';
        temp[j+1]='4';
        temp[j+2]='0';
        j=j+2;
    }

    else if(input[i]=='.')
    {
        temp[j]='%';
        temp[j+1]='2';
        temp[j+2]='E';
        j=j+2;
    }

    else
    {
        temp[j]=input[i];
    }
}
temp[j]='\0';

return temp;
```

}

Error

```
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\emailIDConverter.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  defFile.def
1>c:\users\kpatilx068118\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\emailidconverter\emailidconverter\deffile.def(1): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'string'
1>c:\users\kpatilx068118\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\emailidconverter\emailidconverter\deffile.def(1): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>  converter.cpp
1>c:\users\kpatilx068118\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\emailidconverter\emailidconverter\converter.cpp(39): error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'char [64]' to 'char'
1>          There is no context in which this conversion is possible
1>  Generating Code...
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:01.06
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Your code will overflow `temp[]` and will read outside of `input[]`.

Comment: In C++ (and C), you can't return an array. You will need to find a different way to "return" your result.

Comment: If this is an one time task, you can try vba instead of cpp.

Comment: Yes, I did it in vba ....